# Visual Studio 2015 DNX 451: Invalid reference when adding a 4.5.1 class library

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm using DNX 451 and I'm adding a reference to a 4.5.1 class library in the same solution, and I get dependency could not be resolved. I also add a reference to another 4.5.1 class library and it gets added as a package with wont allow me to access it inside the DNX 451 project.

Why are my references not working? Do I need to use a different framework?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Well why are my references not working? Do I need to use a different framework?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a complex [bug](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2016) caused by DNX and Tooling in VisualStudio 2015 in referencing .csproj to .xproj. I found a workaround by modifying the wrap process in the project.json file, located under the **[solution_root]\wrap** folder of your solution. 
You can see all referenced project folders under the **wrap** directory, make sure all their project.json file have a matching DNX version with the actual referenced dnx in your targeting project mine was:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "wrappedProject": "../../Core/Data/Data.csproj",
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../Core/Data/obj/{configuration}/Data.dll",
        "pdb": "../../Core/Data/obj/{configuration}/Data.pdb"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Changed to:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "wrappedProject": "../../Core/Data/Data.csproj",
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../Core/Data/obj/{configuration}/Data.dll",
        "pdb": "../../Core/Data/obj/{configuration}/Data.pdb"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see my targeting framework now matches the referenced DNX version which is DNX 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your OS is windows 7, but if it is windows 7 then we need to install "dotnetversionmanager-x(version)" and "vebtoolsextensionvs14" link to the downloads is "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48222". 
Hopefully this will work.